# Import Error while importing TensorLy in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, tensorly

I'm trying to import TensorLy in Jupyter notebook as `import tensorly as tl` but I'm getting Import Error. I have TensorLy installed on my local machine.

Complete traceback:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-7285d7cdd476> in <module>
----> 1 import tensorly as tl

c:\users\jaydeep borkar\desktop\tensorly\tensorly\__init__.py in     <module>
  2 import sys
  3 
----> 4 from .base import unfold, fold
  5 from .base import tensor_to_vec, vec_to_tensor
  6 from .base import partial_unfold, partial_fold

c:\users\jaydeep borkar\desktop\tensorly\tensorly\base.py in <module>
----> 1 from . import backend as T
  2 
  3 def tensor_to_vec(tensor):
  4     """Vectorises a tensor
  5 

c:\users\jaydeep borkar\desktop\tensorly\tensorly\backend\__init__.py in <module>
  1 import warnings
----> 2 from .core import Backend
  3 import importlib
  4 import os
  5 import sys

c:\users\jaydeep borkar\desktop\tensorly\tensorly\backend\core.py in <module>
  9 import numpy as np
 10 import scipy.linalg
---> 11 import scipy.sparse.linalg
 12 
 13 

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\__init__.py in <module>
115 from .dsolve import *
116 from .interface import *
--> 117 from .eigen import *
118 from .matfuncs import *
119 from ._onenormest import *

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\__init__.py in <module>
  9 from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
 10 
---> 11 from .arpack import *
 12 from .lobpcg import *
 13 

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\arpack\__init__.py in <module>
 20 from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
 21 
---> 22 from .arpack import *

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\arpack\arpack.py in <module>
 43 __all__ = ['eigs', 'eigsh', 'svds', 'ArpackError', 'ArpackNoConvergence']
 44 
---> 45 from . import _arpack
 46 import numpy as np
 47 import warnings

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

What can be the possible solution?

Comment: Have you tried with `!pip install tensorly` inside the Jupyter in a cell ?

Comment: @amrs-tech yes, it says requirement already satisfied. Probably because I have it already on my local machine.

Comment: Check answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53975449/why-do-i-get-this-import-error-when-i-have-the-required-dlls) very similar question.

Comment: I tried that, not working :(

Comment: It seems to be an issue with your installation of SciPy: can you try reinstalling it? Do you manage to import import scipy.sparse.linalg directly?

Comment: @Jean, sorry completely missed this. I reinstalled SciPy with its latest version (1.3.2) but it's still giving me the same error. No,I'm not able to import scipy.sparse.linalg directly. It gives `ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.` I can see SciPy installed on my machine. Could you let me know what might have went wrong?

Comment: @Jean, I tried reinstalling it again. It's working now :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a new conda environment? If so try [this](https://ishikajohari.medium.com/import-errors-in-jupyter-notebooks-972b1011bee6) out.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: add [context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/9193372) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).